# Inequality used in proof of existence of SDE solutions?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, integral-inequality

In the proof of existence/uniqueness of SDE the following inequality is used:

$$E\left[ \left( \int_0^t a(s,\omega) ds \right)^2 \right] \leq t E\left[ \int_0^t a(s,\omega)^2 ds \right]$$

and I cannot really see how it is obtained. Here, $a$ is defined as
$$a(s,\omega) = b(s,X_1(s)) - b(s,X_2(s)),$$
where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are stochastic processes, both of which satisfy the SDE
$$dX_t = b dt + \sigma dBt,$$
and $b$ is assumed to satisfy:

1. $|b(t,x)| \leq C(1+|x|)$
2. $|b(t,x)-b(t,y)| \leq D|x-y|$

for some constants $C,D$. But given neither appears in the inequality, I do not think they are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This inequality uses the (deterministic) Jensen's inequality, i.e.$$
\left( \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t a(s, ω) \,\mathrm{d}s \right)^2 \leqslant \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t (a(s, ω))^2 \,\mathrm{d}s. \quad \forall t > 0,\ ω \in Ω
$$
Multiplying by $t^2$ and taking expectations yields$$
E\left( \left( \int_0^t a(s, ω) \,\mathrm{d}s \right)^2 \right) \leqslant t E\left( \int_0^t (a(s, ω))^2 \,\mathrm{d}s \right).
$$

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of that form of Jensen's inequality. Just found the one you refer to one wikipedia page. Many thanks!